# Round datetime values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to round datetime values in intervals of an hour or an hour and a half in pandas i.e 2019-01-14 17:24:26.792 or 17:05:36.002 should be 17:00:00.000 and i.e 2019-01-14 17:34:26.792 or 17:54:21.542 should be 
2019-01-14 17:30:00.000 any ideas?